# How to perform case sensitive sorting in angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
array = [{"id":1, "name":"aabc"},{"id":2, "name":"Dog"},{"id":3, "name":"James"},{"id":4,"name":"A1"},{"id":5, "name":"112"}{"id":6, "name":"Arjun"},{"id":7, "name":"ball"}, {"id":8, "name":"john"}]
```

I tried this one.

```
array.sort((a,b) => a.name.toLocaleLowerCase().localCompare(b.name.toLocaleLowerCase());
```

but it is not showing the expected output

```
expected output = [{"id":1, "name":"112"},{"id":2, "name":"A1"},{"id":3, "name":"Arjun"},{"id":4, "name":"Dog"},{"id":5, "name":"James"},{"id":6, "name":"aabc"},{"id":7, "name":"ball"},{"id":8,"name":"john"}]
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: Can you please put in the actual output of the sorting function?

Comment: should be `localeCompare` not `localCompare` and your sample data has a syntax error.

Comment: @epascarello That doesn't give expected output. Here it seems that the requirement is to have all upper case starting letter words before lower case.

Comment: in your initial array you have 112 as name for id 5 while in the expected output array you have 112 for it ... something's not ok even with the data

Comment: @AasthaBist not sure why you are telling me it does not work. I was pointing out the typos in the code.

Comment: @epascarello My bad. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort using a comparing function that compares the strings.

```js
var array = [{"id":1, "name":"aabc"},{"id":2, "name":"Dog"},{"id":3, "name":"James"},{"id":4,"name":"A1"},{"id":5, "name":"112"},{"id":6, "name":"Arjun"},{"id":7, "name":"ball"}, {"id":8, "name":"john"}]


var result = array.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (a.name < b.name) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0
})
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method along with a comparison function.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const arr = [{"id":1, "name":"aabc"}, {"id":2, "name":"Dog"}, {"id":3, "name":"James"}, {"id":4, "name":"A1"}, {"id":5, "name":"112"}, {"id":6, "name":"Arjun"}, {"id":7, "name":"ball"}, {"id":8, "name":"john"}];

arr.sort((a, b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1);

console.log(arr);
```